# How can i run a function from a localfile in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

I'm trying to work on some bookmarklets for firefox. as described in this reddit post.
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/s3rhie/advanced_js_bookmarklets_with_params_using/

I've gotten some basic ones to work with js and params in firefox.
[image]

but its really tedious to copy the text over into the URL field every time i want to test my function.
what I would like todo is just have a javascript file on my computer and then have the javascript in the URL field load that file and run a function based on the first argument.

so it would be something like the URL field has the value

```
javascript:(
// import the file that has an object containing url functions
import bookmarklets from "/tmp/bookmarklets.js";


// '%s' might be something like 'reddit math_stuff'
// then bookmarklet_key would be reddit
// and bookmarklet_args would be ['math_stuff']
let bookmarklet_key, ...bookmarlet_args = '%s'.split(' ');
// i think this syntax is not right but I can figure out those details later

// lookup the specific url function in the bookmarklet object and pass the args to it 
let target_url = bookmarlets[bookmarlet_key](...bookmarklet_args);
document.location.href = target_url;
```

an example of bookmarklets.js might look like this

```
const bookmarklets = {
    'google': function(search_term1, search_term2){
          return 'https://google.com/search?' + search_term1 + 'foo bar' + search_term2;
    },
    'reddit': function(path){
       return 'https://reddit.com/' + path;
    }
}
```

then in the firefox i would add it like this
[image]

after that I could type into the url bar
`bm reddit show_me_stuff`
and I'd goto reddit

or i another example `bm google search stuff`

So there's two things that I really don't know about here.
That import statement is mostly psuedo code. I have no idea how to make that work.
`import bookmarklets from "/tmp/bookmarklets.js";`
So how can i add a script/js file object to firefox that I can import somehow. I have to imagine I could add it somewhere on my file system and make it available to the firefox but I just don't know how todo that.

I'm also unclear about the `'%s'` magic. What I know is that if i have a keyword registered with the value `tt` as in the example. Then I type `tt foo bar` into the url bar. then `'%s'` will have the value `'foo bar'`.
but is '%s' a javascript, firefox or just bookmarklet thing?
I mean '%s' works I just don't understand where its coming from.